# Automatic 1px width of div inside table

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

*This happens in Chrome (43.0.2357.124) and Safari (5.1.7) but not Firefox or Internet Explorer.*

For some reason, the `<div>` element in the following code has an automatic width of 1px.

```css
table, tbody, tr, td, div {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}
table, tbody, tr, td {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table><tbody><tr><td><div></div></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

The same happens when applying `display: inline-block;` and `width: 100%;` to the `<div>` to simulate `display:block` with the added bonus that the `<td>` has a height of 18px.

```css
table, tbody, tr, td, div {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}
table, tbody, tr, td {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table><tbody><tr><td><div></div></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

I'm aware that applying `width: 0;` to the `<div>` fixes the problem, so I'm not looking for a way to remove the automatic width. I'm just curious why this happens. Is it a browser bug or does this happen because of some automatic styling of block elements?

Something similar also happens when the `<div>` is not present in the DOM. When the `<td>` is empty, all parent elements have a width of 1px while the `<td>` has a width of 0.

```css
table, tbody, tr, td {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table><tbody><tr><td></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

The issue doesn't seem to be from any of the usual problems: padding, margin, or border, so I can't understand why the div has a width of 1px.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as `div` is being sized based on size of its parent - `td` in this case (`td` width is 1px, you can remove `div` to see that), and this is div's default behavior.
Placing it inside `td` is kind of opening a Pandora box - `div` take its width based on its parent, but `td` size depends on its content.
Different browsers seem to implement it in different ways, and 1px width represents webkit's approach to determining size of empty table cell.

Comment: As for your first comment, removing the `<div>` also removes the problem. With just an empty `<td>`, the width is `0`. As for the paradox being the reason, is that just assumption or do you have a reference? Plus, in that case, why is it `1px` instead of `0` or `100%`?

Comment: Hm. weird stuff really - on my first attempt of removing `div` in web inspector, I get size of `td` 1px x 0. Now repeating the same resulted in size being 0 x 0. Unless I'm not halucinating, I did get 2 different results of my tests, so I did recreate page outside of SO environment, and you're right it's 0 x 0.

Comment: I have a feeling you deleted the `<div>` and when your cursor moved to the `<td>`, it showed the old width. The same happened to me until I moved to a different element and back. It just needed to be recalculated.

Comment: I made my assumptions too early then. Also removing `div` sets `td` to 0x0, but at same time, sets its parent `tr` to 1px x 0. At least in Chrome

Comment: Hmm, that is odd and happens without the `<div>` even being there in the first place, meaning this is likely not (solely) due to the paradox you mentioned. I'll add that to my question.